# Creating generators from user defined data types in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, generator, quickcheck

I need some suggestions on how I can go about creating a random generator for the Foo data type such that the list of Boo is never empty?

```
data Boo = Boo Float Float Float
data Foo = Foo Float Float Float [Boo]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `listOf1` function to get a generator which generates non-empty lists and use that for defining an appropriate `Arbitrary` instance, like:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Applicative

instance Arbitrary Boo

instance Arbitrary Foo where
  arbitrary = Foo <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary <*> arbitrary <*> listOf1 arbitrary
```